# Facebook Deep Linking Not Working for Open Graph News Feed Stories

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, deep-linking, applinks

I'm developing an iOS app that uses a custom URL scheme and supports deep linking. I've tested that the deep linking works by typing my custom URL directly into safari; it takes me to my app. Additionally, when I share a link to my website on Facebook, the link redirects to my app.

The problem I'm having is with Facebook open graph news stories. My app shares open graph stories using the same URL as in my tests, but when I tap to open the news story from my iOS device, it opens in the Facebook browser instead of in my app.

Because sharing the URL directly works, I'm fairly confident I've set up deep linking correctly, so I think it must be something with open graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was caused by a fundamental misunderstanding of how Open Graph works on my part. In the iOS app, I was creating a new Open Graph object rather than linking to the existing OG object stored in a webpage on my server. I didn't need to create a new one, I just needed to link to an existing one. Now, Facebook pulls the metadata from my OG object as expected, and deep links work fine.